# UE4 - Why TArray of UObject are garbage collected?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have some issues with the garbage collector but I don't understand why ?

I have a UObject called "WorldModel" created and stored (pointer with UPROPERTY) in the GameInstance.

In this "WorldModel" UObject I have an array of UObjects called "WorldPlayerModel" (TArray) with the UPROPERTY macro.

When I load a new map, my "WorldModel" is still here, the array of "WorldPlayerModel" too but all the UObjects inside it are destroyed by the garbage collector and nulled.

According to the doc my UObjects should not be destroyed so I don't understand why ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the link. I don't really understand why it can works with a custom name but I have found my real problem : the UObjects in the array was created with an Outer that was destroyed during the new map loading... It seems ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... There was already someone asking the same question long ago: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/410789/tarray-of-uobjects-getting-garbage-collected.html ;
Try to name your objects (at least to try his solution, even if it is only a workaround)

Answer (score 0):

Even I follow the workaround, I still get crash.
So I declare eash UObject in .h like
PROPERTY()
UObject* aObj;

PROPERTY()
UObject* bObj;

In my case, I reuse those uobject.